# Get tablename from regclass in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, function

I would like to get Tablename from `regclass` in PostgreSQL. I have found a work around but I am not feeling so happy with it:

```
SELECT split_part('datastore.inline'::regclass::TEXT, '.', 2);
```

Is there a dedicated function to extract table name from regclass in Postgre?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can query [pg_class](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/catalog-pg-class.html):

```
select relname 
from pg_class 
where oid = 'datastore.inline'::regclass;
```

There is no built-in function but you can create your own one:

```
create or replace function get_relname(regclass)
returns name language sql as $$
    select relname 
    from pg_class 
    where oid = $1
$$;

select get_relname('datastore.inline'::regclass);
```